# In IE, delete of non-existent property fails if object is in another window. Why?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cross-window-scripting

Normally, code such as:

```
var x = {};
...
delete x.foo;
```

should not cause any errors, even if foo is never defined on `x`.

However, in IE (but not Chrome or Firefox), if `delete x.foo;` is called from code in a *different window* than the one `x` was created in, it throws an "**SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support this property or method**" error if the `foo` property doesn't exist.  (It works fine if it *does* exist).

Here's some test code you can save to a HTML file and run yourself:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Window 1</title>
    <script>
      var x = {}, win2, d;
      function makewindow2()
      {
        if (win2&&!win2.closed) win2.focus(); else win2 = window.open("", "win2");
        d = win2.document;
        d.open();
        d.write(
'<!doctype html>\n'+
'<html>\n' +
'  <head>\n' +
'    <title>Window 2</title>\n' +
'    <script>\n' +
'      var win1 = window.opener, win1x = win1.x;\n' +
'    <'+'/script>\n' +
'  </head>\n' +
'  <body>\n' +
'    This is Window 2\n' +
'    <br><br>\n' +
'    <input type="button" onclick="delete win1x.foo;" value="Click to delete property foo from Window 1\'s x object">\n' +
'    <br><br>\n' +
'    <input type="button" onclick="win1x[\'foo\'] = true;" value="Click to set property foo on Window 1\'s x object">\n' +
'  </body>\n' +
'</html>');
        d.close();
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    This is window 1
    <br><br>
    <input type="button" onclick="makewindow2()" value="Click to create Window 2">
    <br><br>
    <input type="button" onclick="delete x.foo;" value="Click to delete property foo from the x object">
    <br><br>
    <input type="button" onclick="x['foo'] = true;" value="Click to set property foo on the x object">
  </body>
</html>
```

(You'll need to click "Allow Blocked Content" for both Window 1 and 2).

You'll note that in Window 1, you can set or delete `foo` in any order, any number of times.  But in Window 2, if you try deleting it before it's set, or deleting it twice in a row, you'll immediately get an error (in IE 11).

My question is,

(a) What's the underlying cause of this behaviour, and

(b) Is this documented somewhere? ('cause I couldn't find it).

(Also, I though a stackoverflow entry documenting this odd behavior might help out people for whom it may be causing difficult-to-diagnose bugs... :-)  )